Make the instructions added to a given hook in the end applied in a different order
Let's suppose that, in the source file of a class, different instructions are added to the same hook (e.g. begindocument/end) in different (potentially distant) places, and in a certain order. Is there any way that, at the end of this file, these instructions can in the end be applied in a different order from the one in which they were added?
As an example, I would like the following MCE to display “FooBar” instead of “BarFoo”.
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{myclass.cls}
\ProvidesExplClass
  {myclass}
  {2024-05-23}
  {0.1}
  {
    My~Nice~Class.
  }
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\LoadClass { article }

\hook_gput_code:nnn {begindocument/end} {.} {Bar}
\hook_gput_code:nnn {begindocument/end} {.} {Foo}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{myclass}
\begin{document}
\end{document}


give them a unique label, e.g. ./bar and ./foo then you can sort them with a rule.

\hook_gset_rule:nnnn { begindocument / end } { . / foo } { < } { . / bar } \hook_gput_code:nnn {begindocument/end} {. / bar} {Bar} \hook_gput_code:nnn {begindocument/end} {. / foo } {Foo}
